# Transforming xml with XSLT to add keys on lower level

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to format my xml and copy some fields to a lower level so I have keys when I will import it to Access.
Trying to add the field Number to the Part of ActivityLog.
The same way I did it for the identifier but I don't find a way to do it for the number 
I cannot adapt the xml because this is an export of an application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
            <NotificationReport xmlns="http://www.xyyyxx.com/extraction/notification">
                <NotificationElement>
                  <Identifier>13689</Identifier>
                  <NotificationElementAcceptance>
                    <NotificationElement>
                      <VersionNumber>
                        <Number>2</Number>
                      </VersionNumber>
                      <NotificationElementAcceptance>
                        <ActivityLogs>
                          <ActivityLog>
                            <ActivityLogId>NE-720177</ActivityLogId>
                            <ActivityStartDateTime>2015-11-03T17:09:30.475</ActivityStartDateTime>
                            <CreationDateTime>2015-11-03T17:09:30.475</CreationDateTime>
                            <ActivityIndex>1</ActivityIndex>
                            <CompleteProcessStatus>Change notification element</CompleteProcessStatus>
                          </ActivityLog>
                        </ActivityLogs>
                      </NotificationElementAcceptance>
                    </NotificationElement>
                  </NotificationElementAcceptance>
            </NotificationElement>
            </NotificationReport>
```

--> The xslt I have created untill now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ActivityLog">
        <ActivityLog>
            <Identifier><xsl:value-of select="../../../../../Identifier"/></Identifier>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ActivityLog>
    </xsl:template>
```

Expected result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <NotificationReport xmlns="http://www.xyyyxx.com/extraction/notification">
           <NotificationElement>
              <Identifier>13689</Identifier>
              <NotificationElementAcceptance>
                 <NotificationElement>
                    <VersionNumber>
                       <Number>2</Number>
                    </VersionNumber>
                    <NotificationElementAcceptance>
                       <ActivityLogs>
                          <ActivityLog>
                             <Identifier>13689</Identifier>
                             <VersionNumber>2</VersionNumber>
                             <ActivityLogId>NE-720177</ActivityLogId>
                             <ActivityStartDateTime>2015-11-03T17:09:30.475</ActivityStartDateTime>
                             <CreationDateTime>2015-11-03T17:09:30.475</CreationDateTime>
                             <ActivityIndex>1</ActivityIndex>
                             <CompleteProcessStatus>Change notification element</CompleteProcessStatus>
                          </ActivityLog>
                       </ActivityLogs>
                    </NotificationElementAcceptance>
                 </NotificationElement>
              </NotificationElementAcceptance>
           </NotificationElement>
        </NotificationReport>
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired output of your example? This would help a lot.

Comment: The expected result is added in the question ( Didn't get the makup correct)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to namespaces. You have declared a default namespace in your XML

```
<NotificationReport xmlns="http://www.xyyyxx.com/extraction/notification">
```

This means that element, and all descendants (unless overridden without another namespace declaration) are part of that namespace. Elements in a specific namespace are different to elements that are in a different namespace, or have no namespace, even if the element has the same name.

In your XSLT, there is no reference to the namespace at all. So, when you do `<xsl:template match="ActivityLog">` it is trying to match an element called `ActivityLog` that is in no namespace, which is not the case for your XML.

The solution is to declare the namespace in your XSLT, and include it in your template match.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:n="http://www.xyyyxx.com/extraction/notification">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="n:ActivityLog">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../../../../n:Identifier" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the namespace prefix `n` is arbitrary. It is the namespace URI it is linked to that must match the input XML.

Comment: The namespace was wrongly copied ( I changed it because of the name in the url( Company wise).

Comment: It's OK to change sensitive details when you post a question. You just need to make sure you declare the namespace in your XSLT too, using the same URI as specified in the XML.

Comment: You can read up on namespaces in XML and XSLT at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html and http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution(        )

--> So i can go up and after that go down again in other Node. :) Noob in Xml.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="heal:ActivityLog">
    <heal:ActivityLog>
        <heal:Identifier><xsl:value-of select="../../../not:Identifier"/></heal:Identifier>
        <heal:VersionNumber><xsl:value-of select="../../not:NotificationElement/not:VersionNumber"/></heal:VersionNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </heal:ActivityLog>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Where do the `heal` and the `not` namespace come from?

Comment: This stylesheet is incorrect because it is malformed XML. There are undeclared prefixes, as the previous commenter has noted.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is right about the namespaces (see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855544/948404) for explanation). The following transformation actually turns the given input (as published in the question) into the expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.xyyyxx.com/extraction/notification"
    xmlns:n="http://www.xyyyxx.com/extraction/notification">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="n:ActivityLog">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../../../../n:Identifier"/>

            <VersionNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../../n:VersionNumber/n:Number"/>
            </VersionNumber>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You might want to consider accepting one of the answers then. Tim's because it was the first to get the namespaces right or mine, as you see fit. This will earn you and the author of the accepted answer some reputation. Welcome to StackOverflow!